# MAX of SUMs from GROUP BY of JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm stuck.

I have two tables:

First, `[PurchasedItemsByCustomer]` with the columns:

```
[CustID] INT NULL,
[ItemId] INT NULL,
[Quantity] INT NULL,
[OnDate] DATE NULL
```

Second, Table `[Items]` with the columns:

```
[ItemId] INT NULL,
[Price] FLOAT NULL,
[CategoryId] INT NULL
```

I need to output a list with 3 columns:

- a month
- the category which sold the most (in items quantity) in that month
- how many items from that category were purchased in that month.

Thank you

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask]. Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: First: Think of your requirement (What is "a month" and how about a year?). Second: Try to solve the problem (How to group the records? What to calculate? How to keep only the highest sum?). Third: Ask a question here showing what you have done so far, the output of what you have done and let us know your desired output. Sample data would be useful.

Comment: I suspect you don't really want `[Price]` to be a `FLOAT`, you probably want a `DECIMAL(12,2)` or some such.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
;With SoldPerMonth as (
    select datepart(month, p.onDate) [Month], i.CategoryId [Category], sum(p.Quntity) [Count]
    from PurchasedItemsByCustomer p
    join Items i on p.ItemId = i.ItemId
    group by datepart(month, p.onDate), i.CategoryId
), SoldPerMonthRanked as (
    select *, rank() over (partition by [Month] order by [Count] desc) rnk
    from SoldPerMonth
)
select [Month], [Category], [Count]
from SoldPerMonthRanked
where rnk = 1;
```

[**SQL Server Demo**](https://rextester.com/BATU67620)

> Note: In above query by using `rank()` will provide all max categories if you want to return just one row use `row_number()` instead.

Comment: Why the CTE? Why `DATEPART` instead of `MONTH`.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
SELECT
            A.[CategoryId],
            A.[Month],
            A.[CategoryMonthCount]
    FROM
            (
            SELECT
                        A.[CategoryId],
                        A.[Month],
                        A.[CategoryMonthCount],
                        RANK() OVER(
                            PARTITION BY A.[Month] 
                            ORDER BY A.[CategoryMonthCount] DESC) [RN]
                FROM
                        (
                        SELECT
                                    I.[CategoryId],
                                    MONTH(PIBC.[OnDate]) [Month],
                                    SUM(PIBC.[Quantity]) [CategoryMonthCount]
                            FROM
                                    [dbo].[PurchasedItemsByCustomer] PIBC
                                JOIN
                                    [dbo].[Items] I
                                GROUP BY
                                    I.[CategoryId],
                                    MONTH(PIBC.[OnDate])
                        ) A
            ) A
    WHERE
            A.[RN] = 1;
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: One remark: It should be SUM(Quntity), not COUNT(*).

Answer (score 0):

Divide et Impera:

```
with dept_sales as(
select month(ondate) as month, year(ondate) as year, category, count(*) as N -- measure sales for each month and category
from purchase join items using itemid
group by year(ondate), month(ondate), category)

select top 1 * --pick the highest
from dept_sales
where year = year(current_timestamp) -- I imagine you need data only for current year
order by N desc --order by N asc if you want the least selling category
```

If you don't group by year you'll get january of all the years in the same 'january' entry, so I added a filter on current year.

I used CTE for code clarity to split the phases of calculation, you can nest them if you want to.